# WP-API Custom Post Type json_no_route

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, wp-api

I have created a custom post type and extended the WP_JSON_CustomPostType class as in the documentation, I can see the custom type when I go to wp-json/ but as soon as I go into wp-json/quizes it gives this error, any help would be great. PS: Im new to plugin dev.

```
register_post_type('quiz',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Quizes' ),
            'singular_name' => __('Quiz'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' =>true,
        'show_ui' =>true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    )
);


public function quizno_api_init($server)
{
     global $quizno_api_quiz;

     $quizno_api_quiz = new QN_API_Quiz($server);
     $quizno_api_quiz->register_filters();
}



/**
* wp-api extension
*/
class QN_API_Quiz extends WP_JSON_CustomPostType
{
    protected $base = 'quizes';
    protected $type = 'quiz';

    public function register_routes($routes)
    {
            $routes = parent::register_routes($routes);
            return $routes;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your code directly to your question. Two reasons, 1.) It is frustrating switching screens to get your code 2.) if that paste is ever removed, your question will be useless to others. Please file an [edit]

Comment: Sorry about that, did as requested

Comment: Any progress on this? API is a bit different these days.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is missing in your code is the "add_action" call for your plugin init function, so all gets instantiated correctly within `wp_json_server_before_serve` hook. Should be something like this (note the last line):

```
function quizno_api_init($server)
{
     global $quizno_api_quiz;

     $quizno_api_quiz = new QN_API_Quiz($server);
     $quizno_api_quiz->register_filters();
}
add_action( 'wp_json_server_before_serve', 'quizno_api_init' );
```